# Stack count not working properly

Tags: c#, stack

Why my code is not working as expected?
trying to check if stack.Count>0 and it is not working properly

toShort("../../../z") is returning "../z", but it should return "../../../z"
**UPDATE:**

```
static String toShort(String path)
    {
        String[] elements = path.Split('/');
        String result = "";
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
            if (stack.Count>0&&elements[i].Equals(".."))
                stack.Pop();
            else
                stack.Push(elements[i]);
        }
        List<String>list = new List<String>();

        foreach (String str in stack)
            list.Add(str); 
        list.Reverse();
        int n = list.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (i != n - 1)
                result += list[i] + "/";
            else
                result += list[i];

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What does it do? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the top conditional?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you told us what you expected it to do and what it is actually doing.  Also what `elements` datatype is and what's in it.

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working properly".

Comment: "../z" is what I would expect it to return.  Why do you think that it should be "../../../z"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is doing exactly what you told it to do. The stack is working correctly. The second `..` causes the first `..` to be deleted. You would have noticed this if you stepped through the program in a debugger.